# EF Core RC2 AppDomainUnloadedException

Tags: exception, appdomain, entity-framework-core

Since i've updated EF Core from RC1 to RC2, the tests are passing on my local VS2015, but not in TFS Build (VSTest).

For the tests failing, i'm using the In-memory test provider as follows:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the in-memory database, as recommended by the EF Core  
    /// documentation.
    /// </summary>
    private DbContextOptions CreateNewContextOptions()
    {
        var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
        builder.UseInMemoryDatabase()
               .UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);

        return builder.Options;
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        //Arrange
        var contextOptions = CreateNewContextOptions();
        var dataMapper = new DAL.DataMappers.BuurtcampagneDataMapper(contextOptions);

        //Act
        dataMapper.Add(_buurtcampagne);
        var count = dataMapper.FindAll();

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(1, count);
    }
```

The data access is as follows:

```
    ctor blabla..    
    private DbContextOptions _options;

    public IEnumerable<Buurtcampagne> FindAll()
    {
        using (var context = new BuurkrachtContext(_options))
        {
            var query = context.Buurtcampagnes
                .ToList();
            return query;
        }
    }


    public void Add(Buurtcampagne buurtcampagne)
    {
        using (var context = new BuurkrachtContext(_options))
        {
            context.Buurtcampagnes.Add(buurtcampagne);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

The error stack trace is as follows:

```
System.AppDomainUnloadedException : Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain.
at System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle.Unwrap()
at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.CacheEntryHelper.get_Scopes()
at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.CacheEntryHelper.EnterScope(CacheEntry entry)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.CacheEntry..ctor(Object key, Action`1 notifyCacheEntryDisposed, Action`1 notifyCacheOfExpiration)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.MemoryCache.CreateEntry(Object key)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.CacheExtensions.Set[TItem](IMemoryCache cache, Object key, TItem value)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
at Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at InfoSupport.BSBuurkracht.DAL.DataMappers.BuurtcampagneDataMapper.FindAll() in D:\4\_work\2\s\BSBuurkracht\InfoSupport.BSBuurkracht.DAL\DataMappers\BuurtcampagneDataMapper.cs:line 62
at InfoSupport.BSBuurkracht.DALTests.EFCoreDataMapperTests.BuurtcampagneDataMapperTests.TestMethod() in D:\4\_work\2\s\BSBuurkracht\InfoSupport.BSBuurkracht.DALTests\EFCoreDataMapperTests\BuurtcampagneDataMapperTests.cs:line 49
```

Who can help me?